# Is the untyped lambda calculus consistent if equations containing non-β-normal forms are void?

Tags: lambda-calculus

Consider the function $f = \lambda x \mapsto \neg (x\ x)$ where $\neg$ is negation.

It then follows that

$$
f\ f = \neg (f\ f) 
$$

Thus proving a contradiction, but $(f\ f)$ is an expression that does not have a $\beta$-normal form. This expression simply never returns. My intuition tells me that we can't say anything about the equivalence between the two terms because they're both irreducible to $\beta$-normal form.

Does voiding expressions containing non-$\beta$-normal forms make the untyped lambda calculus consistent?

Comment: What is $\lnot e$ for a term $e$? I've never seen it used at a value level, only at a type level.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor $\top = \lambda xy.x$, $\bot = \lambda xy.y$, $\neg = \lambda x.x \bot \top$.

Comment: You know, in hindsight, I have seen that before... Thanks for clarifying ^_^